# Does Postmessage work between individual web pages under the same domain? If so, how?

Tags: html, postmessage

In my code, I have this:

```
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("some_iframe").contentWindow; //sending part
iframe.postMessage("X", 'http?://example.com');
</script>
```

On the receiving page, I have

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event) { alert(e.data); } // no security concerns here, just the message is needed
</script>
```

When I look into the console of the sending page, I get this error:
Unable to post message to http?://example.com. Recipient has origin http?://www.example.com

Can't post more than two links, whatever so I put a ? just after `http`. Not actually in the code.

Actually, I think I found the answer. It's subtle, but www is what's interfering, right? But just to be sure, you *can* use postMessage for communication between two documents on the *same* server?

Some example code would be great as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in detail about how postMessage works and the quirks when dealing with same-or-cross-domain and sandboxing in this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/). For basic reference see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

In short, you can do postMessage between any two windows, no matter the domain.

Now that I think of it, just to be clear, both windows have to be open under the same document tree, meaning they must have a common parent document (as in the same browser tab on the same device). I am not sure if you think you can achieve this on different browsers or tabs or devices, which is not the case, and you must look at web-sockets and webRTC for that, as this is a completely different feature.